# Configuring Codeigniter framework on Linux

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

I've installed Codeigniter on Linux CentOS.

I extracted everything to my web directory, set everything up, and everything worked fine.

Next I moved my `application/` and `system/` folders outside the web directory, and then provide full path to them in `index.php`.  The folders I provided resolve fine from the command line, but I continue to get the error:

> Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

Here are the full path locations:

```
$system_path = '/data/utilities/codeigniter/system/';
$application_folder = '/data/utilities/codeigniter/application/';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions were not set correctly... silly mistake.  I did this to fix it:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /data/utilities/codeigniter/
```

Answer (score 1):

First, is `utilitities` a typo only here, or in your index.php, too?

Second, does Apache have full access to `/data`, `utilities`, **and** `codeigniter`?

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions of the folders? The Apache user might not have access to those folders. You can find out the permission by using the command `ls -la` and then set the owner or group to the Apache user `chown www-data:www-data -R /data/utilitities/codeigniter/system/`
and `chown www-data:www-data -R /data/utilities/codeigniter/application/` (Assuming that the Apache user is www-data).